# Rigorous plane wave expansion in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime, plane-wave

I work with quantum field theory in curved spacetimes, so I'm not fully aware of the notation used in standard QFT. However, I'll try to make myself clear. In standard QFT, the one-particle Hilbert space is taken to be the space of complex, square-integrable solutions of the Klein-Gordon equation, which has positive frequency (with respect to the notion of time of inertial observers). Is that correct?

Frequently, any function $f$ in this Hilbert space is expanded in terms of plane waves as
\begin{equation}
  f(t,\mathbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3\mathbf{k}\,\varphi(\mathbf{k})\,u_\mathbf{k}(t,\mathbf{x}),
\label{expansion}
\end{equation}
where

\begin{equation}
  u_\mathbf{k}(t,\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}k_0^{1/2}}e^{-ik_0t}e^{i\mathbf{k}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{x}}
\end{equation}
and $k_0\equiv\sqrt{\mathbf{k}^2+m^2}$, $m$ being the field mass. This "basis" is "orthonormal" in the sense that
\begin{equation}
  \langle u_{\mathbf{k}},u_\mathbf{k'}\rangle_{KG}=\delta^3(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k'}),
\end{equation}
and the field operator is written as
\begin{equation}
\hat{\phi}(t,\mathbf{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3\mathbf{k}\,\left[u_\mathbf{k}(t,\mathbf{x})\,a_\mathbf{k}+\overline{u_\mathbf{k}(t,\mathbf{x})}\,a_\mathbf{k}^\dagger\right].
\end{equation}

Now, here is my question: rigorously, $u_\mathbf{k}$ is not square-integrable, so it can't be called an "orthonormal basis" (in the sense of Hilbert basis). Furthermore, the expression I wrote for the field expansion in modes is not rigorously convergent. I know that the field operator can be interpreted as an operator-valued distribution, and that all these quantities become rigorously defined when smeared with test functions. How can I interpret these expressions more rigorously? Maybe this plane wave basis makes sense when we define a suitable generalized measure $\mu(\alpha)$ and write
\begin{equation}
f=\int d\mu(\alpha) \varphi(\alpha) u_\alpha \;\;\;?
\end{equation}
If this is the case, can someone please explicit to me this measure construction?
Thank you!

Comment: Fields are tempered distributions. Fourier transform is well-defined for tempered distributions and is itself a tempered distribution. Generally, I would expect that these questions are addressed in Wald's book or Streater-Wightman, although I don't remember.